# Continues to loop back to initial value python

Tags: python, loops, break

Im only 3 weeks into attempting to learn python, so im not fully sure what im doing.  Im trying to make a short simple and stupid game where i use randint to give a random value in a fight between the player and computer.  The health value keeps looping back to the original value and i cant seem to figure out why... Been searching for days.  I put a break in to stop the fight but it doesnt have either 'health' reach zero.  Thanks for any help.

```
from random import randint

n = input()
print ('Welcome, ', n, ' Choose your weapon: Sword, Axe, or Mace.')
b = input()

if b == {'Sword'}:
    print ('Good Choice ', (n), ' the Sword will keep you safe.')
elif b == {'Axe'}:
    print ('Good Choice ', (n), ' the Axe will do some damage.')
elif b == {'Mace'}:
    print ('Probably a bad choice ', (n), ' the mace is heavy and slow but may protect you.')

print ('The Knight Approaches! ', (n), ', Get your', (b),' and get ready!')


player = 50 
knight = 50

battle = True

while player >= 0  or knight >= 0:

    if b == 'Sword':
        k2 = (knight - randint(3,4)) 
        p2 = (player - randint(2,6))
        print ('You have struck the knight!  His health is now', k2)
        print ('He has hit you as well!  Your health is now', p2)

    elif b == 'Axe':
        print ('You have struck the knight!  His health is now', knight - randint(2,6))
        print ('He has hit you as well!  Your health is now', player - randint(3,4))

    elif b == 'Mace':
        print ('You have struck the knight!  His health is now', knight - randint(0,7))
        print ('He has hit you as well!  Your health is now', player - randint(2,6))

    if player <= 0: 
        print ('You have died...')
    elif knight <= 0:
        print ('You have won!')

    break

print ('Good Game')
```

Comment: You're only ever changing the health values when `b == 'Sword'`.  The other times you're printing information but never setting the variables.

Comment: Even then, nothing changes.  He calculates `k2`, but then it is only printed, it is never reassigned back to the original `knight` variable.

Comment: It seems to have worked.  Thanks everyone for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't changing your health values anytime other than when the player picks the sword. When you are printing information you didn't set the variables yet. Notice how you only have k2 = (knight - randint(3,4)) or p2 when b == 'Sword'.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the result of `knight - randint(2,6)` does not change the value of knight.

I think you may want something like this instead:

```
damage = randint(2, 6)
knight = knight - damage
```

Answer (score 0):

you are printing k2 and p2, which are assigned again each run, and which have no memory of the previous run. i.e. your player and knight variables never change. Why not just do:

```
if b == 'Sword':
        knight = knight - randint(3,4) 
        player = player - randint(2,6)
        print ('You have struck the knight!  His health is now', knight)
        print ('He has hit you as well!  Your health is now', player)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the block of code that begins on line 24: if b == 'Sword':

Instead of using k2 and p2 for reassigning the knight and player health, use the same variable as the initial assignment outside of the loop, player and knight.

```
knight = (knight - randint(3,4))
player = (player - randint(2,6))
```

Each time the loop is run, the updated health value will be used.